# When Does Scanner.nextLine() block?

Tags: java

I'm using a Scanner for my socket connection in a Client/Server program.

I want Scanner.next() to block so the Server thread can wait for something to read.

However, it sometimes gives me:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
    at cscie55.hw4.Server.serviceClient(Server.java:146)
    at cscie55.hw4.Server.main(Server.java:106)
```

The java documentation says that next() "sometimes" blocks, and it doesn't say whether nextLine() blocks.

Some code online wraps it in an if that tests for null, but I read that it never returns null. What should I do to get blocking IO working properly in my socket?

Specifically,

When does Scanner.nextLine() block rather than throw NoSuchElementException?

Comment: can you post your code? are you allocating the scanner in multiple locations?

Answer (score 3):

The `Scanner` class will block whenever the `InputStream` used to construct it would block. It will usually not block when reading from a file because the contents of it are readily available (i.e., `inputStream.available() > 0`), they are on your machine after all. However, if you construct a `Scanner` using an `InputStream` that may require waiting for data to arrive (e.g., reading text from a remote client, waiting for a page to load so you can read its source, etc.) then `Scanner#nextLine()` will block because it needs to wait for enough information to build the next line to arrive.

Answer (score 0):

It blocks if it's reading from a network and there is no data or no newline present in the input and it hasn't reached EOS. You must be reading from a file.

Comment: I'm not reading from a file. The error is happening at the end of the first client connection to the Server and then causing future connections to hang. I think I need to wrap my socket scanner in an if block that tests hasNext(). Thank you for pointing out what EOS that allowed me to figure out when it blocks and when it "knows" no more data is coming.