# Java nextLine blocked on socket

Tags: java, sockets, server, console, client

I am using a server and a client where the server sends a string with an unknown number of \n inside. 
Ex:

```
foo1 \n foo2 \n foo3
```

or

```
foo1 \n foo2
```

On the client, due to the blocking nature of socket, I can't try/catch nextLine(), and I need a way to find out how many \n there are client side before a block is made. I would like to avoid changing the server, is there anything I can do client side?

I have tried hasNext(), hasNextLine() but they seem to block as well before returning a result

Other questions which are similar in title:

[Scanner.nextLine() blocks when using InputStream from Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845518/scanner-nextline-blocks-when-using-inputstream-from-socket)

[When Does Scanner.nextLine() block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036054/when-does-scanner-nextline-block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to **send the total amount of bytes or characters** to read, before sending the message, then on the other side, **you first read the total amount of bytes/characters to read** without blocking, then you read the content of the message.

In other words you could implement a simple protocol to send and read your messages instead of only relying on the end of line characters as you obviously can't in your case.